# if condition with float text issue

Tags: java, android, if-statement, try-catch

i did an app on android studio to get the result for multi-text depend on specific calculations , but i have a problem with float in my edit text, the user have the choice to input number in the text or leave it empty, so when he press on the button the app will make a decision upon condition , if the user leave it empty //do nothing, if he input number //go with equation number 1.

Simply in this case i will do sth like this:

```
try {
    n1 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
    n2 = Float.parseFloat(e2.getText().toString());
    n3 = Float.parseFloat(e3.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Invalid Information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}
```

And it works if i have direct action, but in my issue i have multi equations, and there is only one solution and it will be like this:

```
if (n1=="" || n2=="" || n3="")
{  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Invalid Information",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
else
{// do equation1}
```

But, n1,n2,n3 are "float", So these comparison will give an error..
So I need to correct this to work on my app in this way?????!!!!?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a function that tells you if the String can be converted to float like this:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String string)
{
   try  
   {  
      float f = Float.parseFloat(string);  
   }  
   catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
   {  
      return false;  
   }  
   return true;  
}
```

Note that "" (an empty string) cannot be converted to float so the function will automatically take care of them.

Next thing to do is to improve your conditional statement by adding the function calls we just created like this:

```
String n1 = e1.getText().toString();
String n2 = e2.getText().toString();
String n3 = e3.getText().toString();

if (!isNumeric(n1) || !isNumeric(n2) || !isNumeric(n3))
   return "Wrong input";
else
   //   Do your math here
```

Comment: when i did what you wrote i faced another problem: operator * cannot be applied to java.lang.string double

Comment: thx for u , i solved the problem by converting string to float